# MS Chart Controls: Position grid lines between labels

Tags: c#, microsoft-chart-controls

Is there a possibility to format a MS Chart Control chart, that the axis label is rendered between major/minor tick marks?

E.g.: on the X axis

```
|       |       |   x   |       |
|   x   |   x   |       |       |
|       |       |       |   x   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
   1/1     2/1     3/1     4/1
```

instead of default:

```
|       |       |       x       | 
|       x       x       |       | 
|       |       |       |       x 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----
       1/1     2/1     3/1     4/1
```

Comment: I had the same issue, thanks a lot for raising the question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the MajorGrid IntervalOffset to .5 (assuming your Interval is set to 1). Here is some example markup (this markup would be found under the /asp:Chart/ChartAreas/asp:ChartArea nodes):

<AxisX Interval="1">
  <MajorGrid Enabled="True" LineColor="Black" Interval="1" IntervalOffset=".5" />
</AxisX>

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the labels and marks remains aligned to the default grid